# jquery alert(data) shows the data but cannot render inside div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, alert

I've a textarea with id=wraped and it contains some html codes.
I'm trying to send it to fsjquery.php wire ajax get method and save data into sql database.

Before sending the data i'm removing the ids from the html codes which is in the textarea and add a new class to those codes. When alert function is called, it shows the correct data. but, with ajax it renders only the below

```
<div class="dragmenew ui-draggable" style="left: 48px; top: 139px;"></div>
```

links inside it is missing.. where are the remaining codes ..?

i'm just simply echoing the received data: echo "this is the quote ".$quote = $_GET['updatequote'];

```
function fsshowwraped() {
    var datawraped = $('#wraped').html();
    datawraped = datawraped.replace('id="dragme"','');
    datawraped = datawraped.replace('id="dragme2"','');
    datawraped = datawraped.replace('id="dragme3"','');
    datawraped = datawraped.replace('class="dragme','class="dragmenew');
    var obj = $('#obj').html();
    $('#checkwraped').html(datawraped);
    var data = $('#checkwraped').val();
    alert(data);
            alert(datawraped);
    $.ajax({url: 'fsjquery.php',
            data: 'updatequote='+data +'&obj='+obj, 
             type: 'get', 
             datatype: 'html',
              async: false,
              success: function(outData) {$('#bar').html(outData);
    }
    });
```

Data printed on alert(data) is below

```
<div class="dragmenew ui-draggable"  style="left: 48px; top: 139px;">
<a href="?cat=stories&id=366">dddddddddddd</a></div>
<div class="dragme ui-draggable"  style="left: 420px; top: 6px;">
<a href="?cat=stories&id=364">sdddddddddddddd</a></div>
<div class="dragme ui-draggable"  style="left: 616px; top: 134px;">
<a href="?cat=News&id=358">ddddddddddddddddd</a></div>
```

Comment: you have two alerts, are you sure the first one is working? also what is checkwraped? you have filled it with html and then you try do a .val on it

Comment: Add alert(outData); to the success function.

Comment: both alert shows the same string replaced code perfected for sending wire ajax. but, the second alert puts &amp; instead of just '&'

Comment: alert(outData) results:  this is the quote <div class="dragmenew ui-draggable" style="left:5px; top:129px;"><a hre="?cat=stories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out that the problem is caused by the data which i'm trying to send to php file wire .ajax method. It is caused by the character '&' in the data. I've just replaced '&' to a '$'

```
datawraped = datawraped.replace(/&amp;/g,'$');
```

and then replace that '$' in php file.

```
$quote = str_replace('$','&',$quote);
```

It seems my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in success function

```
$('#bar').html(outData.replace(/&amp;/g, "&"));
```

Hoping it will solve your problem

Comment: nope.. i it didn't. i think outData is the data printing in the php file. and i don't think the data is completely sent to the php wire ajax. some problem. i think problem is with this method data: 'updatequote='+data +'&obj='+obj,